# Issue using same zookeeper for Kafka and Mesos

Tags: apache-kafka, mesos, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to setup Kafka and Spark with Mesos on our 8 nodes cluster as following but having issues launching/starting Mesos Agent using zookeeper endpoint of Mesos masters.

1. Install and setup Zookeeper on 3 nodes (server00,server01,server02) (through ***$KAFKA_HOME/config/zookeeper.properties***)
2. Install Kafka brokers on all 8 nodes (and point it to 3 zookeepers by setting following property in its ***$KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties***)

   zookeeper.connect=server00:2181,server01:2181,server02:2181
3. Install Mesos master on 3 nodes (server00,server01,server02) and update ***/etc/mesos/zk*** with following line:

   zk://server00:2181,server01:2181,server02:2181/mesos
4. Install Mesos agents on all 8 nodes.
5. Edit ***/etc/mesos/zk*** file on all other servers to have following line.

   zk://server00:2181,server01:2181,server02:2181/mesos
6. Start Mesos master on all 3 master servers as below (verified that all Mesos master are running and available by launching http://server00:5050/#/, http://server01:5050/#/, http://server02:5050/#/

   sudo /usr/sbin/mesos-master --cluster=server_mesos_cluster --log_dir=/var/log/mesos --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
7. Start Mesos Agent on all 8 servers.
   Example of launching this on server00:

`sudo /usr/sbin/mesos-slave --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos --master=zk://server00:2181,server01:2181,server02:2181/mesos --ip=9.1.69.150`
But above doesn't launch agent.

But following command does which makes me think that perhaps master mesos are not getting registered with zookeepers.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mesos-slave --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos --master=server00:5050 --ip=9.1.69.150
```

Could anyone shed any light as to whether

1. My configuration is not right or
2. If I have to setup separate zookeepers for Mesos cluster?
3. How can I verify if Mesos masters are getting registered with zookeeper?

Once this setup is working, I intend to run Spark on all 8 nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu, at least, `/etc/mesos/zk`, and other config files under `/etc/mesos` are only read by `/usr/bin/mesos-init-wrapper`.   Thus your master isn't seeing your zk config.

You'll either need to launch it with the init script (`service mesos-master start`), run the wrapper manually, or use the `-zk` option to `mesos-master`:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mesos-master --cluster=server_mesos_cluster --log_dir=/var/log/mesos --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos --zk=zk://server00:2181,server01:2181,server02:2181/mesos
```

`

Comment: You are correct. The configuration under `/etc/mesos/zk` and other files are not being read in my case (using Red hat Linux) and starting Mesos Master with `--zk=zk://server00:2181,server01:2181,server02:2181/mesos` option fixed the issue. Thanks!!